# How to add html files to ListView each items and how to use putExtra for them in android?

Tags: android

```
final String[] webView = {"file:///assets/Test.html","file:///assets/Test1.html"};
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Theme1.this,Result_Theme.class);
            intent.putExtra("th0",webView[0]);
        }
        if(position==1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Theme1.this,Result_Theme.class);
            intent.putExtra("th1",webView[1]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml(webView);

Comment: how can I do this I need

Comment: No need to use if condition just use                     `intent.putExtra("selectedWebView",webView[position]);`

Comment: But it is not working I did like that but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String[] webView = {"file:///assets/Test.html","file:///assets/Test1.html"};
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Theme1.this,Result_Theme.class);
            intent.putExtra("th0",Html.fromHtml(webView[0]));
        }
        if(position==1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Theme1.this,Result_Theme.class);
            intent.putExtra("th1",Html.fromHtml(webView[1]));
        }
    }
});
```